# Missing CppUnitTestFramework dll. Stumped on how to fix the problem

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

[image]

I am seeing this problem while trying to run unit tests. Really not sure where to look to fix the problem. Could not find much in microsoft's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It will be under

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\Extensions\Cpp